# buttons next to each other - but each one has its own side

Tags: android, android-layout

I found here an answer to my first question, and I managed to set my two buttons next to each other: xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@id/description"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">

    <!-- Send it Button -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/confirm_it"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:id="@+id/confirm_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/darkCyan"
        android:onClick="sendName"
        />

    <!-- Skip it Button -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/skip_it"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/skip_button"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/darkCyan"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:onClick="skipName"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

now I want to do something else, I still want the two buttons next to each other, horizontaly, but I want each for example SEND button to the very left of the page, and SKIP button to the very right of the page:

Here's what I want:

[image]

Is it possible? and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer is to replace the `LinearLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` and use alignment

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

    <Button ...
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
    <Button ...
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nick Cardoso's answer it's correct and clean and I personally would use that method. If for some reason you absolutely need a LinearLayout you can achieve what you ask in the following way:

1. Add an empty View between your two Buttons (with **0dp** width and **0dp** height).
2. Set it's "**layout_weight**" property to **1**.

Here's some code to help you

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SEND"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SKIP"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the result you get with this code:

[Click for Image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPMry.png)

Comment: Thank you Claff, I will use it, and I agree, in my project sometimes I need a LinearLayout, so it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use LinearLayout. You can try LinearLayout with **weight or weightSum**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

or

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more easy method. If you add a layout between two buttons and if the layout weight is "1". The two buttons are aligned as desired.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_weight="1" /> <!-- I say there -->
        <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```